# selenium-python code management(git) + jenkins integration. Now how to run the test project present on git on jenkins?

Tags: python, git, selenium, jenkins

Using Selenium Webdriver and Python Scripting I have created a project and was able to make a series of test cases in PyCharm that run on Unit Test. Now I'm able to run my test/test-suite using the below command in the terminal

***python -m pytest /test/smoke/test_suite1.py --browser=chrome --baseURL=dev"***

The Project had a directory which contains the WebDriver and Conftest.py file, POM's, Test Scripts etc..

Now my test/test-suite currently run when I am in PyCharm and pass the terminal command. I have moved my project to the Git repository now but also would like to run these test cases in Jenkins via GIT repository.

There are two ways I would prefer doing the CI.

- Schedule a time (once per week) to run through the tests and send email of result.
- Upload my test cases to a repository on GitHub and when there is a change done to the repository, run the tests and/or on a schedule (once per week).

Ive honestly tried to look up tutorials (videos/documents) but they all seem very unclear.

Is it better to do this with a Jenkins Plugin? If so what are the things I need to add/change to allow this to happen, and configure in Jenkins.